# Docker Storage in AWS. S3, EBS or EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ebs, docker-swarm

I have just moved companies and I am building a new docker swarm on aws. In my last organisation everything was on premises.

I am trying to understand my options for persistent volumes, and see that rexray now offer docker certified plugins for all three storage systems.

I have been trying to look into my options, but a lot of the articles I am reading are 2 year old, which is a lifetime in the docker world.

I understand that to some extent it depends what I am storing, and that depends on the container. Usually it is either config files for the service or a database such as postgres or Mongo.

A few years ago everyone was talking about backing docker with S3, but I am concerned about storing databases there as it seems rather extreme to update the entire object if a record changes.

the old plugin documentation used to say that docker could use "any network attached block storage device", and back then I used flocker with ceph. I have found a few articles (from 2017) talking about performance and high availability going out of the window with EBS?

EFS I know nothing about, but presume it is a file system on top of EBS? and thus prone to the same issues.

Can anyone give me more up to date advice?

thank you

Comment: typically, after searching for hours I post this and then discover cloudstor. it looks like that is the answer

Comment: please submit this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really depends on your use case and cost tolerance.

---

## S3

- Cheapest option of the three
- Can be shared with a multiple hosts
- Redundant
- Highest latency of the three
- Elastic

---

### EBS

- Lowest latency of the three
- Lower cost than EFS, but higher than S3
- Redundant
- *Cannot* be shared with multiple EC2 instances at the same time
- Elastic, but you have to resize the EBS volume and then the file system

---

### EFS

- NFS as a service
- Can be shared with multiple hosts
- Elastic
- Redundant
- Lower latency than S3
- Highest cost of the three